# XAML - Bind to value defined in resources from style defined in resources

Tags: xaml, uwp, xaml-resources

I have a user control with defined resources. 
Here is some code for illustration.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="foregroundColor" Color="Red"/>

    <Style x:Key="buttonFontIconStyle" TargetType="FontIcon">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ???}"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="menuItemLabelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ???}"></Setter>
    </Style>     
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now, I wish to use value defined in foreground color for buttonFontIconStyle, menuItemLabelStyle (and many others). Is it somehow possible to bind to value from resources in resources, or is there a way to specifiy color once (in xaml preferrably) and use it in multiple resources styles?

Comment: Use {StaticResource foregroundColor}

Comment: I was fooled with intellisense typing - that option wasn't available. It was actually one of first things I have tried. After copying your suggestion I see it's working (not intellisense :-) ). Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `StaticResource` :

```
<Style x:Key="buttonFontIconStyle" TargetType="FontIcon">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource foregroundColor}"></Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="menuItemLabelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource foregroundColor}"></Setter>
</Style>
```